# Trouble with ARRAYFORMULA for auto-filling formulas in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm attempting to automatically populate a Google Sheets column in a "Results" sheet with the following formula, which draws data from a "Source" spreadsheet:

=IFERROR(INDEX(Source!$B$2:$D,MATCH($A2&C$1,Source!$B$2:$B&Source!$C$2:$C,0),3)," ")

When I place that formula in ARRAYFORMULA, it does not auto-populate, and changing the MATCH search_key to a range (i.e., $A2:$A&C$1) does not fix the problem.

I.e., neither of these work:

=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(INDEX(Source!$B$2:$D,MATCH($A2&C$1,Source!$B$2:$B&Source!$C$2:$C,0),3)," "))
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(INDEX(Source!$B$2:$D,MATCH($A2:$A&C$1,Source!$B$2:$B&Source!$C$2:$C,0),3)," "))

Is there a way to fix this?  Or an alternative way to automatically fill a formula? I'm also open to using a function other than INDEX/MATCH, so long as it can do a lookup based on two vertical criteria. Unfortunately I don't think a pivot table would suit my purposes, since my "Results" page also queries another spreadsheet to provide other information.

Example here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dsaMYsJeZl2o_rNTLwaVhnEehFvAKRMXghAJeEK220s/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the formula you are looking for:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(HLOOKUP(Source!$D$2,Source!$D$2:$D$11,MATCH($A2:$A4&C$1,ARRAYFORMULA(Source!$B$2:$B&Source!$C$2:$C),0),0),0))
```

I tested this and it works perfectly fine.

---

**TL;DR**

To answer why your formula is wrong,

1. The second argument in `MATCH` should have an `ARRAYFORMULA` otherwise you are basically matching only with first element.
2. `INDEX` doesn't work with `ARRAYFORMULA`. It can only search for a single value in a given range.

The first part can be solved by adding `ARRAYFORMULA` inside `MATCH`.

A simple `VLOOKUP`could have solved the second problem if you weren't searching for a combination of cells (Date and Name). A twisted `HLOOKUP` comes to your rescue.

Without the `IFERROR` part, the formula looks like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(HLOOKUP(Source!$D$2,Source!$D$2:$D$11,MATCH($A2:$A4&C$1,ARRAYFORMULA(Source!$B$2:$B&Source!$C$2:$C),0),0))
```

Answer (score 0):

This formula produces the same output (see cell I1):

`=QUERY({Source!A:D,ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(Source!B:B,'Project Lookup'!A:B,2,0))},"select Col2,Col5,sum(Col4) where Col1 is not null group by Col2,Col5 pivot Col3")`

Comment: Thanks for this -- need to learn more about the Query function.